# What is the Difference Between $\left<x\right>$ and $\bar{x}$?

Tags: notation, average, means

I understand both of these as: "The average of x", but I have a feeling they're not interchangeable.

Mathematically are they the same, or is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{x}$ is usually the mean of a sample, so $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

$\langle x \rangle$ is not typical notation in math in general but in physics it means an average over an ensemble. This informally means adding up each possible value of $x$ weighted by its probability in the distribution of interest. This "addition" is in general described by Lebesgue integration, not summation.

Comment: Thankyou very much, that makes sense, I have generally seen the former case in statistical mechanics!

Comment: @Connor Some authors might use $\overline{x}$ as an ensemble average, you just have to check how they define notation...